It's quite odd to decipher seemingly random key-smashes
soolmgeutrijmnelsjtrhyeyeqabsairessbtewqaryptvocsuorlevveaatcjiupnhgezrbifsgtbosilgbnhocreebeoxntoryalmgautbehrtiuagljannfdwihgfngotrveodoirsetvrfaucstviyoynrse==
I will be adding hints soon, but I expect this to be an easy cipher.


 The odd-positioned characters (with spaces added) spell out "sometimes the easiest way to solve a cipher is to ignore extra material and ignore distractions =".  Presumably the extra material is the even-positioned letters and the distractions are the equality signs — or vice versa.


 And Mithical points out that the rest of it — the even-positioned characters — (with spaces added) spells out "by the way well done for deciphering what most of you probably thought was just gibberish filler =" in rot-13.

